# Does Java remove objects from the heap after a for loop in which that object was created and never used again

Tags: java, for-loop, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a simple for loop in which I create new objects and save to list. After this loop I never used these objects again. Will Java remove these objects from heap or keep them alive before method end because of there are (in stack area) will be several local variables of OrderItem type?

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            OrderItem item = new OrderItem();
            item.setProduct(product);
            item.setQuantity(entry.getValue());
            orderItemList.add(item);
        }
```

Or these objects will live in heap until end of a method (method frame).
But what if move declaration of `OrderItem item` outside the loop.

```
OrderItem item;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            item = new OrderItem();
            item.setProduct(someValue);
            item.setQuantity(someValue);
            orderItemList.add(item);
        }
```

As I understand correctly, in this case in stack area there is only one local variable of OrderItem type and on each loop iteration this variable will reference to new object. And for  objects from previous iterations there are no references and these objects should be removed from heap.

Comment: "for objects from previous iterations there are no references and these objects should be removed from heap."  `orderItemList` has references to those previous items.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman So there is no difference where to declare object reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will Java remove these objects from heap or keep them alive before
> method end because of there are (in stack area) will be several local
> variables of OrderItem type?

I assume that your `orderItemList` is `ArrayList<OrderItem>` in which case adding an `OrderItem` to `orderItemList` should only add a reference pointing to the currently created `item` to your list rather than copying the whole object (as discussed in the linked post).
Then as long as `orderItemList` is around its `OrderItem`s should stay in the heap.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080546/add-an-object-to-an-arraylist-and-modify-it-later#:~:text=The%20reference%20you%20added%20will,the%20reference%20to%20the%20object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080546/add-an-object-to-an-arraylist-and-modify-it-later#:%7E:text=The%20reference%20you%20added%20will,the%20reference%20to%20the%20object).

> After this loop i never used these objects again.

If you are using  `orderItemList` again, which I assume you do, since otherwise it is not clear why the list would be created in the first place, you should be using also `OrderItem`s added to it again.

Comment: So there is no difference where to declare object reference?

Comment: There is only a minor difference. If you define `OrderItem item` outside of the loop, the variable `item` containing the pointer to the last created `OrderItem()` will be still accessible after leaving the for loop within its scope.